# Using Javascript validation checks in a Django Project

Tags: javascript, django

I have to make a registration page in a project that uses Django as the backend framework.. In the registration page, I have to input the names, email, password and mobile... During registration, I need to validate email if its a valid format, check if the mobile number is of 10 digits and check if the password is a strong one.. I want to do it using javascript... I have written the code for the form and also the javascript function... But while running on the server I am unable to get the desired validation checks and alerts... Please help what should i do?

signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'signup1.css'%}">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register</title>
    <!--Javascript form validator-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './register.js' %}">
  </head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h1>Signup</h1>
                        <h6>Register yourself</h6>   
                    </div>
                          <form style="text-align: top;" name="myForm" method="POST" action="" onsubmit="validate()" >
                          {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label"><b>First Name</b></label>
                                <input type="text" name="first_name"placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" id="name" required aria-describedby="emailHelp">                                
                              </div>
                              <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label"><b>Last Name</b></label>
                                <input type="text" name="last_name"placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" id="name" required aria-describedby="emailHelp">                                
                              </div>
                              <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label"><b>Mobile Number</b></label>
                                <input type="tel" name="mobile"  class="form-control" id="number" required aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                              </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                              <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label"><b>Email address</b></label>
                              <input type="email"  name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Id" class="form-control" id="email" required aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                              <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label"><b>Password</b></label>
                              <input type="password"  name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control" id="password" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                              <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label"><b>Your Choice</b></label><br>
                              <input type="radio" id="user" name="user_type" value="user">
                                <label for="html">User</label><br>
                                <input type="radio" id="admin" name="user_type" value="admin">
                                <label for="css">Admin</label><br>
                            </div>                 
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <a style="color: aqua; margin-top: 10px;" href="http://localhost:8000/"><small>Already Registered? Click to login</small></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

register.js  (In static folder of the project)

```
function validate() 
      { 
          
          var abc=document.forms["myForm"]["first_name"].value;
          if(abc=="")
          {
              alert("Please enter the first name");
              return false;
          }
          var def=document.forms["myForm"]["last_name"].value;
          if(def=="")
          {
            alert("Please enter the last name");
            return false;
          }
          var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
          var re = "/^[a-z0-9+_.-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+$"
          var x=re.test(email);
          if(x)
          {}
          else
          {
            alert("Email id not in correct format");
            return false;
          }      

          var mobile = document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].value;        
          var check="^(\+91[\-\s]?)?[0]?(91)?[789]\d{9}$"
          var a=check.test(mobile);
          if(a)
          {}
          else
          {
            alert("Invalid mobile number");
            return false;
          }             
      
          var pass=document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
          var checks="^(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.\d)(?=.[@$!%?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%?&]{8,}$"
          var res=checks.test(pass);
          if(res)
          {}
          else
          {
            alert("Password must contain atleast 1 small, 1 capital, 1 numeric, 1 special character and must be atleast 8 characters long");
            return false;
          }
      }
```

Comment: Remove `action` and `methods` from the form tag and put `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form being submitted. After that you can just check the valid and use the fetch method to make the API call or submit the form using the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expressions are formatted as strings, not regular expressions.

For example...

```
// re is string
var re = "/^[a-z0-9+_.-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+$"
var x=re.test(email);

// re is regex
var re = /^[a-z0-9+_.-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+$/
var x=re.test(email);
```